# Restore database with file name variable date script

Tags: t-sql

I want to write a script that will restore the database by database name + today's date. Example: (test_01.05.2018.bak)

```
DECLARE @BackupFile as nvarchar(128);
SET @BackupFile = N'C:\backup\test1' + convert(varchar(12),Day(GETDATE()) -1) + (month(GETDATE()) * 100) + (year(GETDATE()) * 10000) + N'test1.bak'
USE master;
RESTORE DATABASE [TEST] FROM DISK = @BackupFile WITH FILE = 1,
MOVE N'test1' TO N'C:\db\TEST.mdf',  
MOVE N'test1_log' TO N'C:\db\TEST_log.ldf',
NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, STATS = 10
```

Comment: Can you give us more details on what the problem is? Your query pulls yesterdays date and even if it work it would not match your format of `test_01.05.2018.bak.`

Comment: I need the request to rebuild the base for today. What you need to define the variables to point to the backup format test_01.05.2018.bak ?

Answer (score 0):

Your query would have had date in YYYYMMDD and yesterdays date. It errors because of converion.

It could be rewritten with something like

```
DECLARE @BackupFile as nvarchar(128);
SET @BackupFile = N'C:\backup\test1' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8), DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()), 112) + N'test1.bak'
```

You'll still have to edit the other parts of the string as I couldn't make sense of it but this will get your there.

Comment: Aside: The default length of a `Char`, `VarChar`, `NChar` or `NVarChar` is one character most of the time. When it is the target type of a `Cast` or `Convert` then it is 30 characters. Best practice: Always specify a length. And in this case since you are concatenating `NVarChar` strings to get an `NVarChar` result it would be consistent to `Convert` to `NVarChar(8)` rather than `VarChar`. (Style 112 is ISO `yyyymmdd`.)